Connecting CRUD repository to Entity Manager Factory
I am working on a SpringBoot project with multiple modules, each having it's own db connection. I am trying to figure out how does the crud repository know which entity manager to use when calling say .save() by passing an entity into it? It is working fine now, but I am trying to understand the code.

Have created the datasource object
connected the data source object with the Entity factory object
have the crud repository's save function working properly


Can you specify your java,Spring version ?

I solved this issue using Abstract Routing Data Sources. Now I am stuck with another issue, I am not able to add a new data source to the Abstract Routing Data Sources while the application is running. The situation is when there are new users coming in while the application is running.
Java Version : 17 (Azul)
Spring version : 5.3
